# EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'The user name or password is incorrect'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to move a file from a network drive to another server and when I execute this statement. I get an output of

> The user name or password is incorrect

```
DECLARE @SourceFile AS VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @DestinationFile AS VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(500);

SET @SourceFile='\\SHDVNFDBV1\shared-backup\netFORUM_Archive.bak';
SET @DestinationFile ='J:\netFORUM_Archive_TEST.bak';


SET @Cmd = 'COPY ' + @SourceFile + ' ' + @DestinationFile; 

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

Comment: also tried  GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO UserName

Comment: The service account for SQL Server needs write access to both \\SHDVNFDBV1\ (who named that server???) and J:\ - this is not something you can fix inside SQL Server with GRANT. Also writing to a drive root may be problematic due to UAC and other OS restrictions, so consider using J:\some_sub_folder\...

Answer (score 3):

You should check if you have permissions or not

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use \\SHDVNFDBV1\shared-backup\  /USER:domain\username Passw0rd1'
```

Do not copy to root directory as @AaronBertrand mentioned.

As a side note, why are you using SQL Server to do filesystem tasks? This should be done by PowerShell e.g. `Copy-Item c:\scripts\test.txt c:\test`

Comment: Agreed, this is *not* a job for T-SQL in the first place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just curious - is this listed in your [Bad Habits](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival/) series ? If not, this is a good candidate to include - Just a suggestion :-)